# Qt 4.5 - how do I perform a queued connection with a template type?

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to do a connect with a `std::vector<FrameData*>&` using queued connection

```
   connect(this, SIGNAL(process(QVector<FrameData*>&)), 
           this, SLOT(beginProcess(QVector<FrameData*>&),
           Qt::ConnectionType::QueuedConnection);
```

What parameters should I pass for `QRegisterMetaType` for this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use non-const references in signals and slots.

EDIT: ...when using Queued connections.

Comment: Are you sure!?  As far as I know this is only true for Queued connections and non built in types.

Comment: You're right, you can use them in direct connections. Edited my answer. You can't use them in queued connections regardless of whether they're registered metatypes or "built in types".  A queued connection makes a copy of the signal arguments, which can't be done sensibly for references.

Answer (score 2):

std::vector or QVector?
presumably the following should work,

int type = qRegisterMetaType< QVector<FrameData*> >("QVector<FrameData*>");

Comment: Is it possible with std::vector? I figured that perhpas it would be easier to use QVector

Comment: should work with std::vector too, according to the api docs "Any class or struct that has a public constructor, a public copy constructor, and a public destructor can be registered."