# Does QMetaType work with templated Type

Tags: c++, qt

I've `typedef ProxyTray<QImage, ImageCaptureService> TrayType;` in my class (Which *is* QObject but `ProxyTray` is *not* QObject). I am using that type in Signal, Slots as argument type.

does `qRegisterMetaType` accept such type ? How would I model the string type name for parameterized types ?

Comment: did `qRegisterMetaType<TrayType>("TrayType");` in ctor before connecting signal slots. getting `QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'TrayType&'
(Make sure 'TrayType&' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)`

Comment: did you `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276967/qt-4-5-how-do-i-perform-a-queued-connection-with-a-template-type) may be helpful

Comment: How can I do `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` on a templated Type ?

Comment: Looks Like I cannot pass `non-const ref`

Answer (score 3):

You can declare templated metatypes with :

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE_TEMPLATE_1ARG(TemplatedClass)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE_TEMPLATE_2ARG(TemplatedClass)
```

e.g.

```
template<class T>
class Foo { 

};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE_TEMPLATE_1ARG(Foo)
```

allows to pass `Foo<int>`, `Foo<QString>`, etc... to signals and slots.

```
template<class T, class U>
class Foo { 

};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE_TEMPLATE_2ARG(Foo)
```

allows to pass `Foo<int, double>`, `Foo<bool, bool>`, etc...

There are two caveats however :

- This is not part of the official Qt API and may disappear at some point.
- The template types have to be themselves registered using `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`: `Foo<Bar>` requires `Bar` to be registered as a metatype too (as
  of Qt 5.6)

Comment: Can those macros be used with something nested like this: MyVector<QPair<KeyType, ValueType>> ?

Comment: I don't think so, but as a stopgap measure you should be able to reimplement what the macro does yourself, it mostly is about giving a static name to the metatype id

Answer (score 1):

Yes, templated types can be used in Qt signal/slots. As you already have a `typedef` for your type, you can simply use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` as in the following example:

```
#include <QtCore>

template <typename T>
struct Proxy
{
    T data;
};
typedef Proxy<QImage> TrayType;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(TrayType)

class Donor : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Donor()
    {
        m_proxy.data = QImage(10, 20, QImage::Format_Mono);
    }

    void test()
    {
        emit produce(m_proxy);
    }

signals:
    void produce(const TrayType& proxy);

private:
    TrayType m_proxy;
};

class Acceptor : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void consume(const TrayType& proxy)
    {
        qDebug() << "The mage size is" << proxy.data.size();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QScopedPointer<Donor> donor(new Donor);
    QScopedPointer<Acceptor> acceptor(new Acceptor);
    QObject::connect(donor.data(), SIGNAL(produce(TrayType)),
                     acceptor.data(), SLOT(consume(TrayType)));

    // Test the signal-slot connection.
    donor->test();
    return app.exec();
}
```